# Удаление из базы сайтов по отмеченным чекбоксам

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() { 
    $('#sitedel').click(function(){ 
        var sitecount = $('#siteform input:checkbox:checked').size(); 
        var sitevalue = $('#siteform input:checkbox:checked').val(); 
        if(sitecount == 0) alert('Вы не выбрали сайт для удаления'); 
    else { 
        $('#siteform input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){

            window.location = 'delsite.php?id='+$(this).val();

        });

    } return false;

  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Есть такой код, который перенаправляет на страницу удаления сайта из базы по id, если отмечен чекбокс. Так вот, когда отмечаю несколько боксов, удаляется только первый. Почему???

Answer (score 2):

Это происходит, потому что когда вы выполняете `window.location` страница перегружается и соответственно выполнение скриптов останавливается, есть несколько вариантов решения. Первый - ajax запросами. Тогда будет выглядеть так:

```
$('#siteform input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
$.get('delsite.php',{id:$(this).val()},function(data){
//Здесь можно что то сделать. Ответ сервера будет в переменной data
}); 
});
```

Второй - открывать в новом окне. Тогда вместо

```
window.location = 'delsite.php?id='+$(this).val();
```

используем:

```
window.open('delsite.php?id='+$(this).val());
```